# combining "if matched" logic from re module with use of groups()?

Tags: python, regex

I found myself writing a block of code that looks like this, where I go through a bunch of different possible regex matches for each line of text.

```
for line in someText.splitlines():

    matchObj = re.search(lineproto, line)
    if matchObj:
        do_lineproto_stuff( matchObj.groups(1), matchObj.groups(2) )

    matchObj = re.search(inRate, line)
    if matchObj:
        do_inRate_stuff( matchObj.groups(3), matchObj.groups(4) )

    matchObj = re.search(outRate, line)
    if matchObj:
        do_outRate_stuff( matchObj.groups(5), matchObj.groups(6) )
```

which works just fine — it just seems like there should be some more elegant way to do both the conditional to see **if** I matched the regex and if so, then use the `groups()` construct all in one shot.  But maybe not... it just seems like a lot of repeated code, that's all...

Comment: What’s the type of `some_text`? As for your question, it’s a bit difficult to answer given that this is such an abstract example.

Comment: you have to provide at least one pair of input/expected for us to try

Comment: Side-note: You've got illegal terminal `:`s on a few lines here (all the `search` lines), and it's not necessary to wrap `sometext.splitlines()` in `iter()`; `for` loops, by their very nature, always begin by *implicitly* calling `iter` on the thing being iterated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) provides the assignment expression (`:=`, the "walrus operator") in Python 3.8+ precisely to simplify this sort of code a bit. With it, you can simplify to:

```
if matchObj := re.search(lineproto, line):
    do_lineproto_stuff( matchObj.groups(1), matchObj.groups(2) )

if matchObj := re.search(inRate, line):
    do_inRate_stuff( matchObj.groups(3), matchObj.groups(4) )

if matchObj := re.search(outRate, line):
    do_outRate_stuff( matchObj.groups(5), matchObj.groups(6) )
```

Doesn't avoid separating the test from the use, but dropping your lines of code by a third ain't half bad.

Comment: unsure why this was downvoted, despite the imperfect question this was precisely the answer I was looking for.  My system is python 3.5 so I can't use it, but one day...  ;-)